# Are there any differences between "a slew of" and "a lot of"?

Tags: difference, idioms

I looked them up in the dictionary and it seems they both means *a large number of something*. Somebody on the Internet says that *a slew of* can only be used to refer a lot of people, which I don't agree with. I want to know are there any differences between them? Can you hear this usage in daily life?

My English is too plain, and I plan to use *a slew of* more in the future to make my English more interesting if they have the same meaning.

Comment: You don't say where you are from. According to Oxford dictionaries  _a slew_ meaning _a large number_ is a North American usage (it isn't familiar to me), and not limited to people.

Comment: I'm from North Korea. North American is fine to me as I'm willing to learn American English, not British English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between " a slew of" and "a lot of" is that the first is regional (US English), and also informal, whereas the second is neither. Use regional and/or informal usages with care, and avoid them unless you are absolutely confident that they are appropriate.

> Slew   noun [ C usually singular ]   **US informal**   a large amount or
> number:

[Slew (Cambridge Dictionaries)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slew)